# Pass list from Razor page to code behind to bulk insert using Dapper

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, dapper

So I've created an HTML table on a Razor page as shown below.  Basically I'm just calling a method that returns a list and then using a foreach to go create the rows and controls.  The part I'm completely lost on is how I go about posting this data back to the server and on the code behind using that data to insert back to SQL Server.  I'm using Dapper and I'd like each row of the table to represent a data row, or one object, but how do I get the data from the Razor page passed back as a list of a class?  Not sure if my terminology is accurate here but can you model bind on a list of a type?  Would appreciate some assistance thanks!

[image: Table]

[image: Code sample]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'm so far off track (or so few people use asp.net core and Dapper) that I'm not getting any help.  But someone very helpful marked down my question without commenting - thanks so much.

I realised the key thing I was doing wrong was trying to circumvent model binding, so I created a class/type Rating that represents each row (each column as a property) and then an Assessment type/class that contains a List as one of the properties.

On the Razor page:

```
@foreach (Comp c in Model.GetComps())
        {                
            count++;
            Model.assessment.Ratings.Add(new Rating());
            Model.assessment.Ratings[count].AchievedCompetencyID = c.AchievedCompetencyID;
```

Code behind:

```
public void OnPost()
    {
        using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(Startup.conStr))
        {
            long assessID = con.Insert(assessment);
            foreach (Rating r in assessment.Ratings)
            {
                r.AssessmentID = Convert.ToInt32(assessID);
                con.Insert(r);
            }

        }
    }
```